# Delete lines that contain only spaces

Tags: awk, sed

Consider following file.

```bash
Dalot
# Really empty line
Eriksen
   # Line containing space
Malacia
        # Line containing tab
# Really empty line
Varane
```

How do I remove line that **ONLY** contain either whitespace or tab on it, and leaving empty line intact. The other answer here mostly will remove all empty line including spaces and tab.

Following is desired output.

```bash
Dalot
# Really empty line
Eriksen
Malacia 
# Really empty line
Varane
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using awk:

```bash
awk '/^$/ || NF' file
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -E '/^[\t ]+$/d'
```

i.e. "If the line contains spaces and tabs only, remove it".

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\S/!d' file
```

Delete all lines that do not contain at least one non-white spaced character.

Alternative:

```
sed '/^\s*$/d' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/^(|[^\t ]+)$/' file
```

or

```
$ sed -En '/^(|[^\t ]+)$/p' file
```

print if no chars or at least one non-whitespace char.

Note that **@choroba** did the reverse of this logic to delete lines, which is actually smarter.

Answer (score -1):

```
cat file | tr ' ' | tr '\t' > f2
mv f2 file
```

Comment: This uses neither awk nor sed. (Most shells allow `< tr …` - no need for cat for specifying a file as input for a pipe.)